# MYSQL query is slow using group by with order by

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query that is using a group by and an order by, but it's very slow! I need some help to get the index correct. This is the query I'm running:

```
select *
    from puresen_mv_shop.cache_deals
where feature_ids REGEXP 'i,t,d'
and phone_cost > 100.00
group by handset_numeric_id
order by popularity
LIMIT 0,10;
```

explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  cache_deals index       popularity  5       10  6635320.00  Using where; Using temporary
```

This runs in about 3 seconds, but I need it under a second. There are over 600k rows in the table. Here is the table structure:

```
mysql> describe cache_deals
        -> ;
    +-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | deal_id                 | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | deal_id_replication     | varchar(150)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
    | handset_numeric_id      | int(10)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | handset_url             | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | image_url               | varchar(50)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | handset_id              | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | phone_cost              | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | tariff_numeric_id       | int(10)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | tariff_id               | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | tariff_name             | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | network_name            | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | network_numeric_id      | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | term                    | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | minutes                 | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | texts                   | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | data                    | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | org_line_rental         | decimal(10,2) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | effective_monthly_cost  | decimal(10,2) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | free_gift_id            | int(10)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | free_gift_name          | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | cashback                | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | free_lr                 | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | half_lr                 | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | clearance_flag          | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | manufacturer_numeric_id | int(5)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | manufacturer_name       | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | full_handset_name       | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | popularity              | int(20)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | handset_colour          | varchar(50)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | feature_ids             | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | operating_system        | varchar(30)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    +-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here are the indexes I've currently got on this table:

```
mysql> show index from cache_deals;
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name             | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------
| cache_deals |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | deal_id_replication     | A         |      663532 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | handset_numeric_id      |            1 | handset_numeric_id      | A         |         759 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | network_numeric_id      |            1 | network_numeric_id      | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | tariff_numeric_id       |            1 | tariff_numeric_id       | A         |        1091 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | manufacturer_numeric_id |            1 | manufacturer_numeric_id | A         |          23 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | operating_system        |            1 | operating_system        | A         |          42 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | image_url               |            1 | image_url               | A         |         755 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | tariff_id               |            1 | tariff_id           | A         |        1091 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | term                    |            1 | term            | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | minutes                 |            1 | minutes                 | A         |          26 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | texts                   |            1 | texts                   | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | data                    |            1 | data                    | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | org_line_rental         |            1 | org_line_rental         | A         |         128 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | effective_monthly_cost  |            1 | effective_monthly_cost  | A         |        2147 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | free_gift_id            |            1 | free_gift_id            | A         |         105 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | cashback                |            1 | cashback                | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | free_lr                 |            1 | free_lr                 | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | half_lr                 |            1 | half_lr                 | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | clearance_flag          |            1 | clearance_flag          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | handset_colour          |            1 | handset_colour          | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
| cache_deals |          1 | popularity              |            1 | popularity              | A         |         718 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE
|         |               |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------
```

Am I indexing this table correctly?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3):

That `REGEXP` is killing the potential performance since it can't use an index.  Can that part of the query be written some other way or possibly normalized to another table?  If you can, that will probably help.  Other than that, a composite index on `phone_cost` and `handset_numeric_id` should help.  Also adding `popularity` to that index might help, but MySQL is already unhappy with the query since you're not really supposed to be able to work with columns that aren't in the `GROUP BY` clause.

As a side note, the data types of the columns could be more efficient.  `int(5)` works the same as `MEDIUMINT` due to the limit on the `INT` except that `MEDIUMINT` is one byte smaller. Also, `int(20)` doesn't make sense since the `INT` type can't be that large.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select [name the columns you actually want returned]
      from puresen_mv_shop.cache_deals
     where feature_ids = 'i,t,d'
       and phone_cost > 100.00
     order 
        by popularity
     LIMIT 0,10;
```

Index features_id or (features_id,phone_cost)

Comment: `REGEXP` is not the same as `=` and cannot make use of indexes.

Comment: I need the group by because I need to return a single deal for each handset id. I'm using REGEXP because the feature_id field needs to match on multiple letters, and each handset might have upto 15 features in that field.